# Missing view privileges in USER_TAB_PRIVS

Tags: oracle, view, permissions

I can't figure out how to view the grant privileges I've given users on views --

```
FIRSTUSER@SQL> create view remotetabletest
  2  as select * from A_TABLE where PKEY = '123456'
  3  /

FIRSTUSER@SQL> grant select on remotetabletest to USERB;
FIRSTUSER@SQL> exit

[... login as USERB ...]

USERB@SQL> select count(*) from FIRSTUSER.remotetabletest;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        1

USERB@SQL> select * from user_tab_privs where TABLE_NAME = 'remotetabletest';

no rows selected
```

Normally, if this were a table, querying `user_tab_privs` would return a line about 'GRANT SELECT', but for views I get nothing.

I also tried querying `dba_tab_privs` from SYS: nothing.

(Also, in reality, I'm creating the view over a DB Link, but that doesn't seem related to my problem here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unquoted identifiers in SQL are implicitly converted to upper case, so the statement `create view remotetabletest` creates the view named `'REMOTETABLETEST'`, not `'remotetabletest'`.

In other words, the following should return the expected result:

```
select * from user_tab_privs where TABLE_NAME = 'REMOTETABLETEST'
```

Comment: Nice! That did it -- now I can stop banging my head against the wall